# Make input offer options while typing?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

i have the following situation:

someone needs to select a player that is currently playing (may be more than 2 depending on the sports)

i wanted to make a `<select>`but it ends up too big to select quickly.
i can't let a regular text-input, i want them to type the name correctly.

is there a library / code exemple on how to offer choices / force them WHILE ENTERING DATA.

ie:
i type `tri`
it offers me `tristan BlaBla`

What i tryed :

```
$('#inputID').val(GET NEXT NAME THAT STARTS WITH CURRENT VAL);
```

PROBLEM : it gets annoying and set user out of focus every time.

---

TLDR: something like Google search predictions.

Comment: Have you searched for autosuggest plugins? http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin

Comment: exactly. THANKS! - i speak mostly french, didn't knew how they were called :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See jQuery UI's Autocomplete http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

```
<script>
    $(function() {
            var availableTags = [
                    "ActionScript",
                    "AppleScript",
                    "Asp",
                    "BASIC",
                    "C",
                    "C++",
                    "Clojure",
                    "COBOL",
                    "ColdFusion",
                    "Erlang",
                    "Fortran",
                    "Groovy",
                    "Haskell",
                    "Java",
                    "JavaScript",
                    "Lisp",
                    "Perl",
                    "PHP",
                    "Python",
                    "Ruby",
                    "Scala",
                    "Scheme"
            ];
            $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
                    source: availableTags
            });
    });
    </script>



<div class="demo">

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
</div>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```